# JPOS extract a hexadecimal field

Tags: java, iso8583, jpos

I'm using JPOS for parsing my ISO8583-87 message.

For a particular field i need to extract it as it is in the hexadecimal message.

In the binary message, the length of the field is 60.

I'am using a xml file configuration for my ISOPackager.

I failed in the retrieving process, i tried IFB_HEX, IFB_LLHEX, IFB_LLHBINARY, IFB_BINARY in the isoField type class, none of them work.

Do you know wich type i must use ?

Thank you for your time.
Julien

Comment: Difficult to tell without reading the spec for that particular field.

Answer (score 0):

Have in mind that how the specific ISO8583 field is packed depends on sender. 
You have to ask sender what format for specific field is used so you can use the same on receiving side.

Otherwise you can provide here message dump so somebody can try to help you to recognize packaging method used on sender side.